VS Code terminal with oh-my-posh is showing strange characters

These characters are always showing up on my VS Code terminal. How do I fix it? I was installing Oh-My-Posh, the Powershell looks normal in Windows Terminal. Only in VS Code does the terminal look weird. I have installed and applied the Nerd Fonts.
How to fix this, or is there some kind of specific configuration for the VS Code terminal?

It would be helpful to know what character to which you're referring

I am a little confused, what is it that you are after? The output, depending on what it is supposed to be shown, that you didn't show us, seems to just be encoded wrong
